# Tune my code to solve a puzzle

Tags: performance, perl, puzzle

5 monkey share n peaches, they cannot distribute equally. So the first monkey dump 1 peach, and total number of peaches can be divided by 5, and the first monkey took his part.

Then is the second monkey, -1 peach, can be divided by 5 and took his part.
Until the fifth monkey finished all the steps. There may be some peaches still left.

Give the minimum number of peaches that satisfy this condition.

perl code 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
for $n (0..10000){      #this is basic idea but code is too messy !
    if( ($n-1) % 5 == 0 ){
     $remain = 4/5 * ($n -1 );
         if( ($remain - 1) % 5 == 0){
           $remain = 4/5 * ($remain -1 );
           if( ($remain - 1) % 5 == 0){
               $remain = 4/5 * ($remain -1 );
               if( ($remain - 1) % 5 == 0){
                   $remain = 4/5 * ($remain -1 );
                   if( ($remain - 1) % 5 == 0){
                      $remain = 4/5 * ($remain -1 );
                      print "remain: $remain original: $n\n";
                   }
               }
            }
          }
     }
 }
```

perl code 2:

```
sub doit($){
    ($n) = @_;
    if( ($n - 1) % 5 ==0 ){ #if can be distributed by 5 monkey
       $n = ($n - 1) * 4/5;  #commit distribute
       return $n;
    }else{
       return -1;  #fail
    }
}

for $n (0..10000){   #restriction
    $r = $n;    #"recursively" find solution
    $o = $n;    #backup n
    $count = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){  #assume there is 5 monkey, it can be changed
       $r = doit($r);
    if($r == -1){   #skip once fail
        last;
    }
    $count++;
    }
    if($count == 5){ # if pass 5 test, then you found the number !
       print "now ".$r."\n";
       print "origin ".$o."\n";
    }
}
```

I am thinking to cut some code. But felt hard. Can anyone help ?

Comment: first of all you are not using strict and warnings!

Comment: This question does not deserve downvotes.  Compared to all of the show-me-the-code postings, CodeFarmer has given it a good try, twice.  It could use a better description at the top though.

Comment: Yeah, I voted it down, for some really scary global use, but later changed my mind because it is actually a good question. The problem is that it won't let me un-downvote!

Comment: @Joel: Just so you know, you can do an edit to the question (without changing anything) to unlock the downvotes so you can remove yours.  Might be frowned upon, i dunno -- but it's better than letting an undeserved downvote stand if you've changed your mind.

Comment: @cHao, thanks, I did have to change something so that it would take, but no one will notice the space I added at the end of a paragraph!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you really should use `strict` and `warnings` pragmas at the top of your scripts. Your `$n` usage is especially worrisome. In the future, if you declare variables with `my` but use the same name, you convey the fact that they will represent the same quantity, without the fear that they might collide.

Anyway here is a slightly polished, and more importantly `strict` and `warnings` safe version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub doit {
    my ($n) = @_;
    if( ($n - 1) % 5 ==0 ){ #if can be distributed by 5 monkey
       $n = ($n - 1) * 4/5;  #commit distribute
       return $n;
    } else {
       return undef;  #fail
    }
}

OUTER: for my $n (0..10000){   #restriction
    my $r = $n;    #"recursively" find solution
    for (1..5){  #assume there is 5 monkey, it can be changed
       $r = doit($r);
       next OUTER unless defined $r;
    }
    # if code gets here, then it passed 5 test, then you found the number !
    print "now: $r\torigin: $n\n";
}
```

And now, if you really want to be fun with it (don't use this in production, readability first! ):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

OUTER: for my $n (0..10000){ 
    my $r = $n;
    $r = ($r - 1) % 5 ? next OUTER : 4/5 * ($r - 1) for (1..5);
    print "now: $r\torigin: $n\n";
}
```

or even golfed:

```
for(0..10000){$r=$n=$_;map$r*=--$r%5?next:4/5,1..5;print"now: $r\torigin: $n\n"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this solution:

```
sub share {
  ($_[0] - 1) % 5 == 0 ? ($_[0]-1)/5*4 : die "unable to share";
}

for my $i (1..10000) {
  eval {
    share(share(share(share(share($i)))));
  };
  unless ($@) {
    print "solution: $i\n";
    last;
  }
}
```

I'm sure there is a monad lurking within.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but instead of searching for the answer, start with the last monkey. The minimum peaches he could take is 1, and even though there could be some left, to get the minimum, assume there are 0 left.  Now, calculate how many peaches the second to last monkey saw, and so on.

There is no need to loop, if you start from the last monkey

```
 # set numPeaches to what the last monkey had
 $numPeaches = 1;

 # then, figure out how many the second to last monkey had, and add to numPeaches

 # and, so on ...

 # until you get to the first monkey
```

Comment: yeah, I know, i just want to try coding something to solve problem. The latest remain of peaches could be any number bigger than 0, in this case, the minimal number is 3121, after the fifth took his part, it still remains thousands